# What is wrong with this code, why the loss in this code is not reducing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function, vgg-net

I have implemented VGG-16 in tensorflow, VGG-16 is reasonably deep network, so the loss should definitely reduce. But in my code it's not reducing.
But when i run the model on same batch again and again then the loss is reducing. Any idea, why such thing can happen.

*VGG-net* is followed from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf).

Training was done on, dog-vs-cat dataset, with image size 224x224x3.

Network parameters are folloing:

lr_rate: 0.001
batch_size = 16

Find code @ [GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/danishansari/8406afd287e64759fd3000e841147351)

Output is as below:

[image: Output]

Comment: Whenever my NN aren't learning, I start with this [list](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607) and work through it. Also, your code is missing some indents.

Comment: @EdgarH Sorry, but indentation is wrong because StackOverflow won't support code section in one go. So I had put segments of code into the code section, I guess that ruined the indentation.

Comment: you can put your code into gist(gist.github.com) and provide link here

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're following architecture variant E from the Simonyan & Zisserman paper you linked - then I found a few problems with your code:

- Use `activation='relu'` for all hidden layers.
- Max pooling should be done over a 2 x 2 window, so use `pool_size=[2, 2]` instead of `pool_size=[3, 3]` in the pooling layers.
- Properly link up `pool13` with `conv13`:

```
pool13 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv13, [2, 2], 2, name='pool13')
```

I don't have any GPU available to test, but with sufficient iterations the loss should decrease.

Comment: thanks for your review, I modified that code as you suggested for the obvious mistakes I made, But this did not helped me, loss is still not reducing.